# Using Unity3D from within Eclipse

Tags: android, unity, eclipse

Is it possible to use Unity3D from within Eclipse?  I've seen that I can import a Unity3D project into Eclipse, but I cannot seem to be able to access classes such as Terrain or Ray.  I don't know if that's because I haven't imported the correct libraries or if that's a limitation and that data can only be accessed by methods within Unity3D.  I am designing an Android game within Eclipse and would prefer to use Eclipse than Unity3D, even if that means my game will only be available for Android.

The only real reason I'm using Unity3d is for use of the 3D terrain and to hopefully help in getting the data, such as slope, terrain type, collisions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Unity is an engine, Eclipse is an IDE. They're fundamentally different things.  In particular, Unity expects you to write most of your code in their scripting languages.

The exception to that rule that Unity provides is their plugin architecture.  It's supported in Unity Pro.  You can find more documentation on that here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html but it's kind of backwards from what you're thinking.  You'd be using Eclipse-written plugins from within Unity.

Comment: From what I understand, Unity3D uses JavaScript.  Is there a way to allow my program to use a Java library as well?  I need to send data via USB from the Android device, and I've already created that library.  The data being sent will be based on the terrain.

Comment: @BLaZuRE: Unity3D is scriptable in C#, UnityScript (a JavaScript like language) and Boo (a proprietary scripting language). You can write C++ plugin as external dll, but I don't think you have C++ bindings to engine function.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to this setup.  Do I need to make a 'plugin' in order to interface with my Java code?  I need to receive & send data from the Java code, to control movement of the model and to get positioning of the model.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just use their scripting languages.

Comment: Boo isn't proprietary, just a little odd... it's Python syntax but with .NET libraries instead of the Python libraries. I've always had the feeling that the Unity folks have a *big* client heavily committed to Boo, since C# and UnityScript seem to have the vast majority of users.

Comment: The thing is, I have to take advantage of connecting to a USB Accessory in Android (in order to connect to an Arduino USB Host Shield).  I know how to do this and have implemented in Java.  I don't see how I would be able to do this in Unity3D, which is why I want to use my Java library somehow.